# Mongo shell will not open after downloading an older version. Mongo command not found

Tags: mongodb, macos, shell, terminal, port

I had mongo 3.4.4 and it was running fine, but our production runs on mongo 2.4.8 so I uninstalled 3.4.4 and downloaded 2.4.8. I run the following

```
> mongodb-osx-x86_64-2.4.8/bin/mongod
```

and the port is waiting for a connection but I can't open the shell. I'm assuming this is due to an error in my path but I can't figure it out. I've also checked the connection in this way in another shell.

```
> nc -zvv localhost 27017
```

And my output is the following:

```
nc: connectx to localhost port 27017 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
found 0 associations
found 1 connections:
 1: flags=82<CONNECTED,PREFERRED>
outif lo0
src 127.0.0.1 port 56308
dst 127.0.0.1 port 27017
rank info not available
TCP aux info available
```

When I open a new terminal window to run the shell I just get that the mongo command is not found. Any help on how to solve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the crash report searched by mongo:

```
com.apple.message.domain: 
com.apple.crashreporter.writereport.wakeups_resource.diag
com.apple.message.signature: mongod
com.apple.message.signature2: UNBUNDLED ||| ??? (???) ((null))
com.apple.message.signature3: wakeups
com.apple.message.result: noop
com.apple.message.summarize: YES
SenderMachUUID: 958E4B3E-0BA1-3E93-A3B1-959D97BC15D5
```

Comment: Type `which mongo`, that should tell you where the binary is.. Chances are that you need to add the path to your .bashrc/bash_profile. That should ateast get you to access the shell. As far as the error is, can you please post log files? In Mac OSX it may be written to system.log. Go to /var/log and run `grep -Rl 'mongo*'`

Comment: I added the crash report - is that what you're looking for as far as the log files go? Also, when I run which mongo, nothing is returned

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out by changing the path with

```
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/mongodb/bin"
```

Not sure what it was previously but this got it set up.